# No-code solution for calendar view of SharePoint news items

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-designer, page-library

MOSS provides you an excellent option to create a "news" site in your portal. 
It adds some "Archive" functionality, but it is very limited - a list of all articles published in that particular site.

My users would like to see something better, a real archive of published articles, browsable by publishing date.

What I've tried so far, is  creating a "Calendar" view in the `http://portal/publishingsite/pages/` library. It works, but when you click a link in this calendar, it opens the "dispform.aspx?ID=123", not "mytestpage.aspx".

Is it possible to create a custom page using SharePoint designer where I can put a calendar (best if it can be browsed as easy as a typical calendar view in a list) and that links to pages in "page display mode" not in "SharePoint list item display mode"?

Maybe you have seen an easy-to-install and easy-to-maintain page archive feature for MOSS?

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
have you tried one of the templates available at: 
[Microsoft SharePoint templates](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/sharepoint/templates/default.aspx)

There i saw some pretty good calendar implementations.
(Try the TimeCard Registration).
I'm not sore if it's reusable,but i'm confident that it's a good starting point.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have seen those, but this does not help when you have to deal with publishing webs and pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/179c74de-525c-4236-83cf-91861e9a7aee

It looks a little danger-esque to modifying MS template files in the 12 hive, but you can clearly see a 'DataItem.DisplayFormUrl' in...

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)"
  href="<%# SPHttpUtility.HtmlUrlAttributeEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.DisplayFormUrl",""))%>
```

Change that and you may be good to go.

You could also perhaps consider customizing `dispform.aspx`: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepointdesigner/HA101191111033.aspx

I suspect, however, that - if you only want to do this with Designer - it's not gonna fly :(

You could look into XSLT for a Data View... but unless you're willing to dish out a little cheddar I don't think you'll find something which is up-to-par with the Calendar view.

Comment: I don't think that the idea about modifying DisplayTemplate of the calendar view is a good idea, since we're using calendar views in other lists, too. And I need this feature only for the "portal part"  of my SharePoint installation. So I think, I'll better make two connected webparts (one for date selector and another for displaying pages in that range). 
But thanks for the answer anyway!